# OS X - Kill a process after login

Tags: login, kill

I have a process that is most probably set to run by managed preferences on my account after I log in. However, I do no use it at all, so I wanted to know if there is a way to automatically kill the certain process after I log in and it starts.

Answer (score 2):

I would write a script that kills the process, and attach it to my login 'hook' http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2420

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it to boot up at all, go to System Preferences, Users & Groups, , Logon Items, and then select the thing you do not want to start. Click the minus (-) button.

If you want it to start up and then get killed, make a script to do the following after startup. Things in <> you have to put info in.

```
killall --<Process Name>
```

For example, `killall --Terminal`

Comment: Small correction: `kill` requires a PID. `killall` takes a process name as argument.

Comment: The third line in the man page for killall says: "killall -- kill a process by name."  Additionally the OP said the process is "most probably set to run by managed preferences." If that is true then he would not be able to remove it from the logon items because it has been added there remotely by the network admin

Comment: I'll edit to fix that.